# Convert uint16 to jint and back JNI

Tags: c, java-native-interface, uint16

everyone. I am writing under Android using JNI. 
I need to pass an "interval" into my C foo() as uint16, but after that i use the same "interval" in return to Java.

C:

```
 static jint func (JNIEnv* env, jobject object,jstring first)
        {
        /*...action...*/
        uint16  interval;
        jint result = foo (ifirst, &interval);
        return result < 0 ? result : interval;
        }
```

I have error below

> error: operands to ?: have different types 'jint {aka int}' and
>   'uint16* {aka short unsigned int*}'

how can i use 'interval' argument to avoid an error and continue correct work of program?

Comment: Is this the code that you actually have? The error message doesn't match: it says that the operands are an int and a *pointer* to `uint16`.

Comment: you are write, after getting an error, i removed the pointer and forgot about it. i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, you need to add a cast to ensure that both conditions of the `?:` operator are the same type.

```
 static jint func (JNIEnv* env, jobject object,jstring first)
 {
    /*...action...*/
    uint16  interval;
    jint result = foo (ifirst, &interval);
    return result < 0 ? result : (jint)interval;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this error suddenly disappeared.